# Google App Script - Importing txt, manipulating it, e-mailing exported txt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm quite new to writing scripts but I'd like to make my work life a little bit easier by automating the things I do on a daily basis. I need to write a code that allows me to take the following steps:

1. Import a tab divided TXT into the current sheet,
2. Copy a VLOOKUP formula into column X2:X, and then end at the first empty row
   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),0)
3. Export as a tab divided file, and e-mail to a specified address.

I don't really mind to import and export manually but while I'm at it I might as well add that functionality. My main issue is how to paste the formula and then copy it down so it matches the rows. I mean that in X2 the formula is shown as above and then in X3 it is K3, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help, and I do apologise if this is a silly question.

Cheers,
Sjoerd

Comment: Have you looked at using =ARRAYFORMULA() to auto-populate the formula down all of column X?  It would look like `=ARRAYFORMULA( IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),0)) and would go into cell X2  You would remove all other values from cell X3:X and this will fill in each row

Comment: That's a great idea, now I just need to paste it in X2 using GAS

Comment: It doesn't stop on the final entry though, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I gave the simple version.  We can expand the formula to fix that.  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(K2:K),,, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,UPS!B:D,3,FALSE),0)))`  I have not tested it, but this should do.  There is also a bigger edit which could be placed in the header.  Doing that means you have a template sheet, copy it and import your data.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks Karl! (I had to remove one of the three comma's to make it work)